# Parameter pack constructor preferred over other constructor calls

Tags: c++, templates, preprocessor, parameter-pack

Consider a constructor accepting a parameter pack, such as

```cpp
template<typename First, typename... Rest> 
consteval explicit foo(const First& first, const Rest... rest) 
    : arrayMember{first, rest...}
        {
        }
```

where First and Rest... all have arithmetic types,

And another, different constructor that takes two arithmetic types:

```cpp
explicit foo(std::size_t low, std::size_t high) { /* ... */ }
```

Imagine now that we wish to call the second constructor taking the two arithmetic types parameters:

```cpp
foo f(3,4);
```

... But this actually calls the constructor that takes a parameter pack.

I am wondering whether there is a way to disambiguate the calls.
For example, is there a way (through preprocessor magics or something) to call the parameter pack constructor with brace initialization (`{ ... }`), and to call the other constructor with direct initialization (`(..., ...)`)?
I have thought of disabling the parameter pack constructor if the passed arguments are 2, but what if I actually wanted to call it with two parameters?

Minimal reproducible example:
https://godbolt.org/z/5P9cEdf7v

Comment: Are `First` and `Rest...` of the same type?

Comment: @paolo yep, they are required to be through std::same_as. (I have left that part out for simplicity)

Comment: Can you show the full definition of `foo` (or at least the bare minimum to compile your example)?

Comment: Sure, I've provided a link to godbolt at the end of the thread.

Comment: Why don't you have the first constructor just take a `T const (&in)[N]` and initialize member variable `_vector` with `in` ? This way, the first constructor can only be called as `vector<int,3> v({0,1,2})` or `v{{0,1,2}}`.

Comment: Note that the constructor is consteval and I’d like it to remain like that. Would I need compile time recursion to initialize _vector through in?

Comment: I would approach this like the standard does and use tag dispatch.  Create a tag like or use `std::piecewise_construct` for the first parameter type and then you can disambiguate between the overloads.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming an implementation similar to this:

```
template <typename T, std::size_t Size>
class foo {
   private:
    T _vector[Size]{};

   public:
    using size_type = std::size_t;

    // .. other constructors ..

    explicit foo(size_type lower, size_type higher) { // (1)
        // ...
    }

    template <typename Stream>
    constexpr void print(Stream& stream) const {
        for (auto x : _vector) stream << x << ' ';
        stream << '\n';
    }
};
```

You can replace your first constructor by one that takes a `const` reference to an array, `T const (&)[Size]`:

```
consteval explicit foo(T const (&in)[Size]) // (2)
    : foo(in, std::make_index_sequence<Size>{}) {}
```

This constructor delegates the initialization of `_vector` to another constructor which exploits the inices trick:

```
template <std::size_t... Is>
consteval explicit foo(T const (&in)[Size], std::index_sequence<Is...>) // (3)
    : _vector{in[Is]...} {}
```

With this implementation:

```
#include <iostream>
int main() {
    foo<int, 3> vec0(3, 4); // calls (1)
    vec0.print(std::cout);

    constexpr foo<int, 3> vec1({3, 4}); // calls (2), which calls (3)
    vec1.print(std::cout);

    constexpr foo<int, 3> vec2{{3, 4}}; // calls (2), which calls (3)
    vec2.print(std::cout);
}
```

Comment: That's *exactly* what I was looking for: genius!
(Read an article about index_sequence and things are starting to be clear now... Thanks!)